# Getting feedback on the the service design element of a UX solution

Tags: copywriting, user-feedback, service-design

I'm designing a feedback flow for a touch-less solution of a restaurant system. In this flow users are able to select any aspect they want to give feedback on. how would you address the service design element (service design factors outside the website) from this selection(option 4). right now i've called it "overall service" however i think it could be phrased more accurately.

[image]

Comment: where are the users when using this? Is this from a mobile app, or kiosk system? Are they there to order, then sit outside?

Comment: @MikeM they can access this from a mobile link using their own device. they will be prompted to give feedback a few mins after receiving their meal (meal prep time + about 20 mins )

Comment: When do you expect people to choose "The overall service"? Is it more like a "Other issue..." option or a "Missing feature..." option? I'm asking because, performance, user friendliness and defect issues can also be related to the overall experience.

Comment: @jazZRo overall service would be more towards offline service design related issues. E.g. The waiting time was too long, I was required to show my screen to varify to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "Customer Service" would encompass the things that you are looking to include, but since it excludes the website related issues, you might just have to indicate that in brackets to make it explicit.